# Changing output of the BibTeX style unsrt

Tags: bibtex

I apologize because I'm a beginner and I would like to change the output of the `unsrt` bibliography style, but I can't found anything in 34th tag pages about BibTeX. Also, I tried with other styles but the closest to what I need is `unsrt` with a little change

I would like an unsorted bibliography style such that the year doesn't appear at the end, but next to the authors' names.

For example:

***I don't want this***

> [1] Robinson G.W., Zhu S.-B., and Evans M.W. Water in Biology, Chemistry and Physics. Experimental Overviews and Computational Methodologies. World Scientific, Singapore, 1996."

***I'd like something like this***

> [1] Robinson G.W., Zhu S.-B., and Evans M.W. (1996) Water in Biology, Chemistry and Physics. Experimental Overviews and Computational Methodologies. World Scientific, Singapore.

Answer (score 3):

May be the style [cj.bst](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/cj.bst) do the job (only for bibtex). You can download the `cj.bst` from the link provided and put it in the same folder as your `.tex` file. An example file follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\author{John Doe} \title{Sample Document}
\begin{filecontents}{myreference.bib}
@string{jgr = "J.~Geophys.~Res."}

@MISC{primes,
   author = "Charles Louis Xavier Joseph de la Vall{\'e}e Poussin",
   note = "A strong form of the prime number theorem, 19th century",
   year = 1879
   }

@INBOOK{chicago,
   title = "The Chicago Manual of Style",
   publisher = "University of Chicago Press",
   edition = "Thirteenth",
   year = 1982,
   pages = "400--401",
   key = "Chicago"
   }

@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
   }

@BOOK{latexbook,
   author = "Leslie Lamport",
   title = "{\LaTeX \rm:} {A} Document Preparation System",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1986
   }

@UNPUBLISHED{btxdoc,
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "{Using BibTeX}",
   note = "Documentation for general BibTeX users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
   }

@UNPUBLISHED{btxhak,
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "Designing BibTeX Styles",
   note = "The part of BibTeX's documentation
                            that's not meant for general users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
   }

@BOOK{strunk,
   author = "Strunk, Jr., William and E. B. White",
   title = "The Elements of Style",
   publisher = "Macmillan",
   edition = "Third",
   year = 1979
   }

@book{vanleunen,
   title = "A Handbook for Scholars",
   author = "Mary-Claire van Leunen",
   publisher = "Knopf",
   year = "1979"
   }

@ARTICLE{Zurek:1993,
   AUTHOR  = {Zurek, R. W. and Martin, L. J.},
   TITLE   = {Interannual Variability of planet-encircling dust activity on {M}ars},
   YEAR    = {1993},
   JOURNAL = jgr,
   VOLUME  = {98},
   NUMBER  = {E2},
   PAGES   = {3247--3259}
}

@Article{Narendra_1990,
  author =       {K.S.Narendra and K.Parthsarathy},
  title =        {Identification and Control of Dynamical System
                  using Neural Networks},
  journal =      "IEENN",
  year =         {1990},
  volume =    {1},
  number =    {1},
  month =     {},
  pages =     {4-27},
  note =      {},
  annote =    {}
} 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

According to the handbook of van Leunen \cite{vanleunen},
this paragraph---and certainly this
section---should be longer than one sentence.

\section{More references}

Here we see if the reference \cite{Narendra_1990}
to the Narendra article comes out OK, in particular,
with volume, number \& pages.

The necessary information for those who would use BibTeX
is available in the 1988 document of Prof.\ Patashnik \cite{btxdoc}.
Interested readers who can read French may also
want to read Poussin's proof\cite{primes}, though
it has nothing at all to do with BibTeX.

\section{Conclusion}

This is the concluding paragraph.  Here I cite another of
Oren Patashnik's books\cite{btxhak} and, again,
van Leunen's and Poussin's \cite{vanleunen,primes}.

\bibliographystyle{cj}  % (uses file "cj.bst")
\bibliography{myreference}      % expects file "myreference.bib"
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this was very useful. I used this bibtex style but i didn't obtain the style that i needed because i was changing order on author names.

I would like to know, how I need to edit the cj.bst, so that, I don't get the year of publication between parenthesis. Also, I wanna know how I need to do, so that I obtain title of periodic publications (Journals) between ""

Comment: @shadraws: You may choose a style for you from http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf and http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html#styles.

Comment: @shadraws: To edit the `cj.bst` file you may open a new question.